# to show html table from sql to asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, model-view-controller

i have problem in showing my data field that already in html code inside sql. need to show it on asp.net mvc.

below is the command of html in asp.net which i already add html as fieldtype so when it read html or textbox it will show the page in html format. but now for table, i cant properly show the exact table, but only the code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3sIQ.png)

the sqldata field action details in html table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlQjB.png)

this is the output, which is not show the exact table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFQBi.png)

help me out!

Comment: You need  to share the code in the question itself.

Comment: Hello nur and welcome to SO! Please try to clarify your question. I can't really tell what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: as in the sql image, i have a field called fldactiondetails which i need to show as output. but what happen is, instead of showing the table, it shows exactly the value inside the fldActionDetails. i want it supposedly in table form

Comment: i already share the image code

Answer (score 0):

```
@Htm.Raw()
```

when you want to render html code stored in sql first you need html tag in ef to actually be able to save it from user end then you are subject of milion of hacking attempt which btw all of them fails and then when you want to reder html what you do is just render it with razor which is `@Html.Raw(_yourContext.YourTable.FirstOrDefault(q=>q.yourPK == yourVariable).yourHtmlField)`

Comment: live on and prosper